# Count length of an array and create the same amount of HTML elements with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to query the length of an array and then use JS/jQuery to create the same amount of new HTML elements client side?

The code I have for the array is:

```
var psC1 = [
'item1',
'item2',
'item3'
];

alert(psC1.length);
```

Which will alert that there's 3 items in the array. I now want to create three iframes on the page, and index the array into the src attribute of each element.

The code I'd use to insert the src of the iframes using the array would be:

```
  $('.test-iframe').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', psC1[$(this).index()]); 
   });
```

What I'm struggling with is after counting the array, is creating three iframes with JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an `iframe` with jQuery, you use the [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) function (or `jQuery` in no-conflict mode):

```
$("<iframe>").appendTo(document.body);
```

Of course, you don't have to append to body, you can put the iframe wherever you need it.

In your case, perhaps something like this:

```
$.each(psC1, function(index, value) {
    $("<iframe>").attr("src", value).appendTo(document.body);
});
```

[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) loops through the array entries.

Comment: Thanks... that creates one iframe, which is a start - what I want is to create 3 of them (or whatever the count of the array comes back with) and then index them.

Comment: @JayDee: Well, you said it was creating them that was giving you trouble. :-) But see the update.

Comment: Oooh, that's nice...Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var x = 0; x < psC1.length; x++) {
   $("<iframe>", {'src': x}).appendTo("body");
}
```

The `$("<iframe>")` syntax creates the element.  `.appendTo` adds it to the DOM.  Note that this will just create iframes with source of "0," "1," and "2," so you probably want something like `'/some/path/?page=' + x` as the `src`.

Note that you could also use `$.each` instead of a normal `for` loop, but it's more expensive and, in my opinion, unnecessary.

Comment: FWIW, the variant of `$` that allows you to specify attributes as a second argument is almost certainly going to be removed from jQuery soon.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's good to know; can you provide a link to the documentation on that?

Comment: @ Explosion: I can't, no, it was an off-comment from Dave Methvin in the context of some other bug report. The complexity around the hyper-overloading of the `$` function is getting to be a bigger and bigger problem (gosh, who knew?). ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks; I personally always thought that the `$("<` syntax was bizarre.  I assume they're going to keep that, but apparently I've been creating elements incorrectly for quite some time

Comment: @ Explosion: Well, it's not *currently* incorrect. :-) And I seem to recall after Dave made that comment, he got pushback. But basically he said to do `$("<element>").attr({ ... })` instead (which promptly sparks the `prop` vs. `attr` debate, argh!).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to create the HTML

```
var iframeHTML = "";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    iframeHTML += "<iframe class='test-iframe'></iframe>";
}
```

then append the HTMLString where you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this cleaner with `jQuery.map`:

```
$('body').append($(psC1).map(function (i, src) {
    return $('<iframe>').attr('src', src);
}).get());
```